# Export default is also exporting code the exported function is being used in

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, chai

I have this function:

```
// menuAnimate() adds/removes the classes for the mobile menu animation
export default function menuAnimate() {...}
```

which I am importing into my mocha test file like so:

```
import { menuAnimate } from '../src/scripts/nav';
```

However, when I run a test involving `menuAnimate`, I get an error this error:

```
/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/andybeverlyschool/src/scripts/nav.js:67
navToggle.addEventListener('click', menuAnimate);

TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

This error is being thrown from code further down within `nav.js`.

```
navToggle.addEventListener('click', menuAnimate);
```

How can I export only the function block?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Could you just comment out the code you don't want to run?

Comment: BTW that's not how you import a default export

Comment: @AndrewLi Well, hjow do you import a default export?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson For default exports, remove the brackets around the import: `import menuAnimate from '...'`

Comment: @AndrewLi Awesome! Thank you! When would I want to use brackets. Also, if I am importing multiple modules, do I use brackets even if 'export default'?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson There aren't brackets for default exports. You use brackets if you are exporting *multiple* things then importing them, called *named exports*, such as `function foo() {}; function bar() {}; export { foo, bar };` then import it as such: `import { foo, bar } from '...'`. `foo` and `bar` are *named* exports here. See more at the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { menuAnimate } from '../src/scripts/nav';
```

says "import this file, and let me access one function from it". There's no importing of only part of a file. If you don't want other stuff in that file to run, then you should split the code into two separate files, or rearchitect your code such that it doesn't run when the file loads.

```
navToggle.addEventListener('click', menuAnimate);
```

specifically seems like something I'd *never* expect to execute when the file loads. If you need to bind a listener, you should export a function from your module to do it, then call that function when you actually want the listener to be bound. e.g.

```
export function initNav() {
    var navToggle = ...
    navToggle.addEventListener('click', menuAnimate);
}
```

The top-level scope of a module should have pretty minimal logic of its own. Loading a module on its own isn't something that should have sideeffects like adding an event listener. Pretty much the only time you'd want that is in the initial application JS file.

Also, as mentioned in a comment, since you do

```
export default ...
```

you'd want to do

```
import menuAnimate from
```

or keep the `import` you have and do

```
export function menuAnimate() {...}
```

without the `default`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the great answer! I really appreciate you throwing in the "specifically seems like something I'd never expect to execute when the file loads. If you need to bind a listener, you should export a function from your module to do it, then call that function when you actually want the listener to be bound. e.g." comment! I'm still learning!

Comment: Can't agree more with this answer. +1!